# Mail aliases El Capitan

Tags: mail.app, alias

I used several aliases on my gmail account that was configured in mail.app.
After upgrading to El Capitan, those aliases just vanished.

There is an option in Preferences>Accounts>Account Information>Alias "Edit Alias". But Mail.app froze when I select that option

I just tried everything I thought of : removing cache, removing all mail accounts and recreating them, removing preferences files, rebooting after each attempt, nothing seems to work.

Is there a solution, I need those aliases for my work.

Errors  in console :

```
07/10/15 10:59:51,584 Mail[393]: *** Assertion failure in -[NSMenuItem setTitle:], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1404.11/Menus.subproj/NSMenuItem.m:949

07/10/15 10:59:51,590 Mail[393]: (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff84817bd2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff866924fa objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8481c8aa +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8e146f46 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 198
4   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a555b34 -[NSMenuItem setTitle:] + 149
5   Mail                                0x00000001027b38b7 Mail + 682167
6   Mail                                0x00000001027b3555 Mail + 681301
7   Mail                                0x00000001027b2ff5 Mail + 679925
8   Mail                                0x00000001027b2cdc Mail + 679132
9   Mail                                0x00000001027b2804 Mail + 677892
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a522c9f -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 1252
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a63340b -[NSNib _instantiateNibWithExternalNameTable:options:] + 677
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a63305b -[NSNib _instantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 143
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a66f47f -[NSTableRowData _unarchiveViewWithIdentifier:owner:] + 612
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a67201b -[NSTableView(NSTableViewViewBased) makeViewForTableColumn:row:] + 367
15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a671911 -[NSTableRowData _addViewToRowView:atColumn:row:] + 283
16  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a67166a -[NSTableRowData _addViewsToRowView:atRow:] + 184
17  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a66fe83 -[NSTableRowData _initializeRowView:atRow:] + 390
18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a66e5e3 -[NSTableRowData _addRowViewForVisibleRow:withPriorView:] + 416
19  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a66e377 -[NSTableRowData _addRowViewForVisibleRow:withPriorRowIndex:inDictionary:withRowAnimation:] + 299
20  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a66d13d -[NSTableRowData _unsafeUpdateVisibleRowEntries] + 1697
21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a66c9fe -[NSTableRowData updateVisibleRowViews] + 233
22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a66c377 -[NSTableView layout] + 178
23  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a60b283 -[NSView _doLayout] + 53
24  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a60af3b -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] + 324
25  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a60b197 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] + 928
26  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a60b197 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] + 928
27  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a60b197 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] + 928
28  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a60b197 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] + 928
29  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a60a474 -[NSView layoutSubtreeIfNeeded] + 950
30  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a629d89 -[NSWindow(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutViewTree] + 82
31  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a69c233 -[NSWindow(NSConstraintBasedLayout) layoutIfNeeded] + 244
32  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a69c127 -[NSWindow _setUpFirstResponderBeforeBecomingVisible] + 63
33  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a69b537 -[NSWindow _doWindowWillBeVisibleAsSheet:] + 169
34  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a69a2fd -[NSWindow _reallyDoOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] + 1355
35  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a698cb2 -[NSWindow _doOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] + 894
36  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a7c491f -[NSApplication _orderFrontModalWindow:relativeToWindow:] + 270
37  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a7cb6df -[NSWindow _beginWindowBlockingModalSessionForSheet:service:completionHandler:isCritical:] + 818
38  Mail                                0x00000001027e185e Mail + 870494
39  Mail                                0x00000001027dfedb Mail + 863963
40  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff92cd1082 _os_activity_initiate + 75
41  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a7c09b5 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 460
42  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a7d2bb2 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
43  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a7d2adc __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke + 131
44  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff92cd1082 _os_activity_initiate + 75
45  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a7d2a39 -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 144
46  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff92cd1082 _os_activity_initiate + 75
47  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a93bb0c -[NSPopUpButtonCell _popUpItemAction:] + 92
48  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff92cd1082 _os_activity_initiate + 75
49  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a7c09b5 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 460
50  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a7c074f -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] + 336
51  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a7c04af -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] + 114
52  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff92cd1082 _os_activity_initiate + 75
53  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a852d18 -[NSMenu performActionForItemAtIndex:] + 131
54  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a852c8b -[NSMenu _internalPerformActionForItemAtIndex:] + 35
55  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a852ae3 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _carbonCommandProcessEvent:handlerCallRef:] + 107
56  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a6f723d NSSLMMenuEventHandler + 708
57  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff893f298e _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec + 1231
58  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff893f1e18 _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec + 404
59  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff89407df6 SendEventToEventTarget + 40
60  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff89451d2e _ZL18SendHICommandEventjPK9HICommandjjhPKvP20OpaqueEventTargetRefS5_PP14OpaqueEventRef + 411
61  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8947d0f7 SendMenuCommandWithContextAndModifiers + 59
62  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8947d0a8 SendMenuItemSelectedEvent + 188
63  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8947cf84 _ZL19FinishMenuSelectionP13SelectionDataP10MenuResultS2_ + 96
64  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8945bf11 _ZL19PopUpMenuSelectCoreP8MenuData5PointdS1_tjPK4RecttjS4_S4_PK14__CFDictionaryPK10__CFStringPP13OpaqueMenuRefPt + 1794
65  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8945afec _ZL26_HandlePopUpMenuSelection8P13OpaqueMenuRefP14OpaqueEventRefj5PointtjPK4RecttS6_S6_PK14__CFDictionaryPK10__CFStringPS0_Pt + 610
66  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8945abe3 _HandlePopUpMenuSelectionWithDictionary + 287
67  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a849b30 _NSSLMPopUpCarbonMenu3 + 6168
68  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a848306 _NSPopUpCarbonMenu3 + 153
69  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a84825e -[NSCarbonMenuImpl popUpMenu:atLocation:width:forView:withSelectedItem:withFont:withFlags:withOptions:] + 356
70  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a8cacc3 -[NSPopUpButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 559
71  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a7cf788 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 669
72  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ad1d575 -[NSWindow _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 6322
73  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ad1e559 -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 212
74  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a763d31 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 517
75  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a6e3ccb -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2540
76  Mail                                0x0000000102748885 Mail + 243845
77  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a54af3e -[NSApplication run] + 796
78  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a514162 NSApplicationMain + 1176
79  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8e5b75ad start + 1
)
```

Comment: The assertion suggests a `null` value is being passed as a menu item title. This error is likely beyond your control. Please can you [report this directly to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/mail.html) as it is a serious bug.

Comment: Thank you! Every report helps. Hopefully someone on Ask Different will see your question and can help you work around the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the icloud preferences in Settings - then signed out of icloud completely. Deleted all the icloud files as it will prompted to do so, then signed back in. My alais in mail app were restored properly when I did this.

Comment: But my problem is with my gmail account, not my iCloud account.

Answer (score -1):

In Mail, go to *Preferences* then select *Accounts*. You'll see **Alias** and can "Edit Aliases."

Comment: Why did this get voted down? It works. I just did it for my Gmail account -- I have about eight aliases I use for various clients for whose clients I offer tech support.

Comment: Because the question says what happened when he tried that: Mail.app froze.